# Some Images don't load on Adapter (Glide)

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I have an adapter where I pull images(around 12) with URLs but some of them don't load. And, its not the image size particularly. None of the images are above 200KB. 
Please take a look at the image below for rough idea:
[image]

Here, `Red` implies the viewholder where the images are not loaded. Whenever I open the app, the `Red` is random. It happens mostly on two or three viewholders.

**Code**

```
 Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView.getContext())
             .load(userClass.getUser_image())
             .apply(
                     new RequestOptions()
                             .centerCrop()
                             .placeholder(R.drawable.blueimage)
                             .error(R.drawable.redimage)
                             .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                             .dontTransform())
             .into(viewHolder.imageViewUsersItemUsersImage);
```

Please note that this only happens on first load. Once the images are cached, they load faster. But my app shows new images most of the times, so I want the images to load at once and faster.
Please help
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try to add .dontAnimate() and then check

Comment: @Bunny Thanks for your suggestion. I tried adding .dontAnimate() but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you try without the RequestOptions? Just completely remove the apply method and try again.

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Thanks for your comment. I did try without RequestOptions but no luck.

Comment: have you tried adding `listener` so you can see actual problem? also post the log here

Comment: And I assume you are calling this in the method onBindViewHolder of the Adapter. Is this correct?

Comment: @RahulGaur I am getting java.net.SocketTimeoutException(timeout) onLoadFailed

Comment: @SaeedEntezari Yes. Thats right.

Comment: @SushanNiroula This maybe caused by Internet connectivity as stated in the log

Comment: @RahulGaur My internet isn't slow or unstable. I guess the issue is different.

Comment: @SushanNiroula try adding `timeout()` in `RequestOptions` to increase `timeout` time